# How to navigate to another page after running mutation successfully in React-query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-query

When I redirect to another page after a mutation, it shows memory leak warning. I tried many ways but I haven't found any solution.

The warning is:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `useEffect` hook to redirect to another page after completing rerender. Here I found a solution using custom hook:

```
import { UseMutationResult } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { To, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export const useRedirectAfterMutation = <T, U>({
  mutation,
  navigateTo,
}: {
  mutation: UseMutationResult<T, Error, U, unknown>;
  navigateTo: To;
}) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mutation.isSuccess && !!navigateTo) {
      navigate(navigateTo);
    }
  }, [mutation.isSuccess, navigate, navigateTo]);

  return mutation.mutateAsync;
};
```

```
const App = () => {
  const createCategoryMutation = useCreateCategoryMutation();
  const createCategoryMutate = useRedirectAfterMutation({
    mutation: createCategoryMutation,
    navigateTo: 'url',
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => {
        createCategoryMutate()
      }}>redirect after mutation</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [useMutation](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useMutation) hook and then in the options use onSuccess option to navigate.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const { mutate } = useMutation((log) => console.log)

mutate('mutating', {
  onSuccess: () => {
        navigate('/url') //your url
      },
})
```

Comment: Actually I tried this way, but it also shows the warning...

Comment: this is the correct answer. My guess is you're using tanstack/react-query v4 and react17? The "memory leak" warning has been removed from react itself in v18 because it's a false positive. There is no memory leak. Ignore the warning.

Comment: see also: https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/82 or https://github.com/TanStack/query/issues/3804#issuecomment-1184212985